# Grant permission on a file basis?

Tags: permissions, security

is there a way to grant access to individual files in a report library? So can I have a report library, and in it a folder and in the folder 3 files where only some people can access file one, and some other people can access file 2, and so on.

I thought about creating groups but not sure if this is the right approach because my SharePoint site already has groups to control who can access different parts of the site.

Answer (score 0):

This answered my question:

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-5b900de3-9123-41c9-aa04-919ae6606d40

You break the inheritance, then remove all users, then add who you want.